# Reducing (Key, Value) where value is a dictionary in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce

I am new to spark and still learning. My problem is that I am using a `map` function to create an Rdd of the form (key, dict) which looks like this `[(0, {‘f_0’:’-0.5’}), (0, {‘f_1’:’-0.67’}), (1, {‘f_0’:’-0.36’}), (1, {‘f_1’:’-1.5’})]`

Desired form reduced by key should be:
`[(0, {’f_0’:’-0.5’,’f_1’:’-0.67’}), (1, {‘f_0’:’-0.36’, ‘f_1’:’-1.5’})]`

I am using `pyspark`, python on databricks

Can someone please help?

Comment: Hi there, did you solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

As  per your question your map function output is say:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
  (0, {'f_0':-0.5}), 
  (0, {'f_1':-0.67}), 
  (1, {'f_0':-0.36}), 
  (1, {'f_1':-1.5})], ["key", "val"])
```

Use the below code with reduceByKey to get your desired output:

```
df.rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b:{**a,**b})
```

Note that the above code will work in python3 version not python2. Hence pyspark python version should be 3.5 or higher.

If your pyspark python version is 2.7 then use below code :

```py
def merge_two_dicts(x, y):
    z = x.copy()   
    z.update(y)    

    return z

merge= df.rdd.reduceByKey(merge_two_dicts)
```